# Parsing Haskell custom data types

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, attoparsec

I have worked my way through the Haskell Koans provided here:
https://github.com/roman/HaskellKoans

I am stuck on the last two Koans, both involving parsing custom algebraic data types. Here is the first:

```
data Atom = AInt Int | ASym Text deriving (Eq, Show)

testAtomParser :: Test
testAtomParser = testCase "atom parser" $ do
    -- Change parser with the correct parser to use
    --
    let parser = <PARSER HERE> :: P.Parser Atom
    assertParse (ASym "ab") $ P.parseOnly parser "ab"
    assertParse (ASym "a/b") $ P.parseOnly parser "a/b"
    assertParse (ASym "a/b") $ P.parseOnly parser "a/b c"
    assertParse (AInt 54321) $ P.parseOnly parser "54321"
```

How can define the variable parser such that it can parse the algebraic datatype `Atom` to pass the assertions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### I.

Parsers of an ADT tend to reflect the shape of the ADT. Your ADT is formed of two disjoint parts, so your parser probably has two disjoint parts as well

```
atom = _ <|> _
```

### II.

Assuming we know how to parse a single digit (let's call that basic parser `digit`) then we parse a (non-negative) integer by just repeating it.

```
natural = let loop = digit >> loop in loop
```

this successfully parses an infinite stream of digits and throws them away. Can we do better? Not with just a monad instance, unfortunately, we need another basic combinator, `many`, which modifies some other parser to consume input 0 or more times, accumulating the results into a list. We'll actually adjust this slightly since an empty parse isn't a valid number

```
many1 p = do x  <- p
             xs <- many p
             return (x:xs)

natural' = many1 digit
```

### III.

What about atoms? To pass the test cases, it appears that an atom must be 1-to-many alphanumeric characters *or* backslashes. Again, this disjoint structure can be immediately expressed in our parser

```
sym = many1 (_ <|> _)
```

We'll again use some built-in simple parser combinators to build up what we want, say `satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char` which matches any character which satisfies some predicate. We can immediately build another useful combinator, `char c = satisfy (==c) :: Char -> Parser Char` and then we're done.

```
sym = many1 (char '/' <|> satisfy isAlpha)
```

where `isAlpha` is a predicate much like the regex `[a-zA-Z]`.

### IV.

So now we have the core of our parser

```
natural <|> sym :: Parser String
```

the `many1` combinators lift our character parsers into parsers of *lists* of characters (`String`s!). This lifting action is the basic idea for building ADT parsers, too. We want to lift our `Parser String` up into `Parser Atom`. One way to do it would be to use a function `toAtom :: String -> Atom` which we could then `fmap` into the `Parser`

```
atom' :: Parser Atom
atom' = fmap toAtom (natural <|> sym)
```

but a function with type `String -> Atom` defeats the purpose of building a parser in the first place.

As stated in I. the important part is that the shape of the ADT is reflected in the shape of our `atom` parser. We'll need to take advantage of that to build our final parser.

### V.

We need to take advantage of information in the structure of our `atom` parser. Let's instead build two functions

```
liftInt :: String -> Atom  -- creates `AInt`s
liftSym :: String -> Atom  -- creates `ASym`s

liftInt = AInt . read
liftSym = ASym
```

each of which stating both a method of turning `String`s into `Atom`s but also declaring what *kind* of `Atom` we're dealing with. It's worth noting that `liftInt` will throw a runtime error if we pass it a string that cannot be parsed into an `Int`. Fortunately, that's exactly what we know we have.

```
atomInt :: Parser Atom
atomInt = liftInt <$> natural

atomSym :: Parser Sym
atomSym = liftSym <$> sym

atom'' = atomInt <|> atomSym
```

Now our `atom''` parser takes advantage of the guarantee that `natural` will only return strings which are valid parses for a natural---our call to `read` will not fail!---and we try to build both `AInt` and `ASym` in order, trying one after another in a disjoint structure just like the structure of our ADT.

### VI.

The whole shebang is thus

```
atom''' =     AInt . read <$> many1 digit
          <|> ASym <$> many1 (    char '/' 
                              <|> satisfy isAlpha)
```

which shows the fun of parser combinators. The whole thing is built up from the ground using tiny, composable, simple pieces. Each one does a very tiny job but all together they span a large space of parsers.

You can also easily augment this grammar with more branches in your ADT, a more thoroughly specified symbol type parser, or failure decorations with `<?>` so that you have great error messages on failed parses.